# Visual studio breakpoint, does it stop whole application process?

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I'm debugging multithreaded C# application for a few hours already, so my question may be stupid, however... when a breakpoint is hit current thread stops it's execution, but are other threads within process keep running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All threads in your application will be halted, and will resume once you exit out of 'step-through' debugging mode.

If you we're doing database calls etc. in that time, depending on the length of time you halted the threads, you will find that they will likely throw a timeout exception.